# How is per-tag reputation calculated?

Tags: support, tags, reputation, profile-page, tag-score

I have a [Mathematica answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3973/700) on a given tag ([pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf)) which has a few upvotes. However, when I look at my [reputation for this tag](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/700/fx?tab=tags&sort=name), I have none. How can that happen?

Comment: The tooltip is quite informative, just hover over the score count.

Comment: Is the "total score" the number of votes or obtained rep points?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler "total score" is `upvotes - downvotes`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [revision history](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/3926/revisions), you just added that tag 14 hours ago. So, that tag isn't yet calculated for you since you haven't had any other questions under it.

**Tag scores are heavily cached.** They are only updated once a day. Your tag scores should be updating sometime in the next 1 to 2 hours. They usually update sometime around midnight UTC. At that time you should see the `[pdf]` tag appear in your profile along with your score.

As usual, have patience. :)

Comment: Yup, 03:00 UTC to be precise :)