# Tag numbers in profile delayed?

Tags: discussion, tags, profile-page, tag-score

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is per-tag reputation calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128588/how-is-per-tag-reputation-calculated)

I am trying to understand the the [tag numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73164/explain-tag-numbers-in-profile) in people's profiles.

When I see a non-wiki answer net voted to 3 and its owner has number 1 shown to the left of its tag in their profile (and no other listed answers in that tag), would that simply mean that I looked there too soon after the last two upvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those scores are cached. They are updated every night at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: +1 at the referenced question and voting to close here.  (I don't know how I missed it.  Thanks.)